# Validação de dados por meio da varredura de um dict em python

Tags: lista, validação, dicionário

Olá, pessoal!

Estou com um problema para montar um código e gostaria de uma certa ajuda.

O problema em questão é: Para cada elemento da minha string, eu preciso varrer o meu dict, especificamente o item na posição [1], comparar este item com o slice da string e retornar a chave correspondente deste dict

#Sequência a ser convertida

_seq1 = 'QVQLKESGPGLVAPSQSLSITCTVSGFPLTAYGVNWVRQPPGKGLEWLGMIWGDGNTDYNSALKSRLSISKDNSKSQVFLKMNSLQTDDTARYYCARDPYGSKPMDYWGQGTSVTVSSAKTTPPSVYPLAPGSAAQTNSMVTLGCLVKGYFPEPVTVTWNSGSLSSGVHTFPAVLQSDLYTLSSSVTVPSSTWPSETVTCNVAHPASSTKVDKKIVPRD'

#Dict onde a busca será realizada

CODONS = {
'UUU': ['FENILALANINA','F','codify'],
'UUC': ['FENILALANINA','F', 'codify'],
'UUG': ['LEUCINA','L','codify'],
'CUU': ['LEUCINA','L','codify'],
'CUC': ['LEUCINA','L','codify'],
'CUA': ['LEUCINA','L','codify'],
'CUG': ['LEUCINA','L','codify'],
'UUA': ['LEUCINA','L','codify'],
'AUU': ['ISOLEUCINA','I','codify'],
'AUC': ['ISOLEUCINA','I','codify'],
'AUA': ['ISOLEUCINA','I','codify'],
'AUG': ['METIONINA','M', 'start_codify'],
'GUU': ['VALINA','V', 'codify'],
'GUC': ['VALINA','V', 'codify'],
'GUA': ['VALINA','V', 'codify'],
'GUG': ['VALINA','V', 'codify'],
'UCU': ['SERINA','S', 'codify'],
'UCC': ['SERINA','S', 'codify'],
'UCA': ['SERINA','S', 'codify'],
'UCG': ['SERINA','S', 'codify'],
'CCU': ['PROLINA','P', 'codify'],
'CCC': ['PROLINA','P', 'codify'],
'CCA': ['PROLINA','P', 'codify'],
'CCG': ['PROLINA','P', 'codify'],
'ACU': ['TREONINA','T', 'codify'],
'ACC': ['TREONINA','T', 'codify'],
'ACA': ['TREONINA','T', 'codify'],
'ACG': ['TREONINA','T', 'codify'],
'GCU': ['ALANINA','A', 'codify'],
'GCC': ['ALANINA','A', 'codify'],
'GCA': ['ALANINA','A', 'codify'],
'GCG': ['ALANINA','A', 'codify'],
'UAU': ['TIROSINA','Y','codify'],
'UAC': ['TIROSINA','Y','codify'],
'UAA' : ['STOP-CODON', 'NON-codify'],
'UAG' : ['STOP-CODON', 'NON-codify'],
'UGA' : ['STOP-CODON', 'NON-codify'],
'CAU': ['HISTIDINA','H', 'codify'],
'CAC': ['HISTIDINA','H', 'codify'],
'CAA': ['GLUTAMINA','Q', 'codify'],
'CAG': ['GLUTAMINA','Q', 'codify'],
'AAU': ['ASPARAGINA','N', 'codify'],
'AAC': ['ASPARAGINA','N', 'codify'],
'AAA': ['LISINA','K', 'codify'],
'AAG': ['LISINA', 'K', 'codify'],
'GAU': ['ÁCIDO ASPÁRTICO','D', 'codify'],
'GAC': ['ÁCIDO ASPÁRTICO','D', 'codify'],
'GAA': ['ÁCIDO GLUTÂMICO','E', 'codify'],
'GAG': ['ÁCIDO GLUTÂMICO','E', 'codify'],
'UGU': ['CISTEÍNA','C', 'codify'],
'UGC': ['CISTEÍNA','C', 'codify'],
'CGU': ['ARGININA','R', 'codify'],
'CGC': ['ARGININA','R', 'codify'],
'CGA': ['ARGININA','R', 'codify'],
'CGG': ['ARGININA','R', 'codify'],
'AGU': ['SERINA','S', 'codify'],
'AGC': ['SERINA','S', 'codify'],
'AGA': ['ARGININA','R', 'codify'],
'AGG': ['ARGININA','R', 'codify'],
'GGU': ['GLICINA','G', 'codify'],
'GGC': ['GLICINA','G', 'codify'],
'GGA': ['GLICINA','G', 'codify'],
'GGG': ['GLICINA','G', 'codify'],
'UGG': ['TRIPTOFANO', 'W', 'codify']
}

#funções construídas

## Tentativa 1

def convert(sequencia) -> list:
elementos = []
for i in sequencia:
for chave, item in CODONS.items():
if i == item:
elementos.append(chave)
print(elementos)

## Tentativa 2

def convert2(sequencia) -> list:
elementos = []
for i in sequencia:
for p in CODONS.keys():
if i == p:
yield elementos.append(p)

## Retorno

Em nenhuma das funções eu recebo qualquer retorno, seja de erro ou qualquer resultado.

Obs: Peço desculpas, caso tenha postado a pergunta de forma incorreta na plataforma, esta é a minha primeira vez. Desde já agradeço toda a ajuda fornecida.

Comment: Só para entender, você quer percorrer os elementos da sua string e comparar com o item[1] da lista das chaves e retornar a chave? Por exemplo: digamos que rode o sistema e pego a primeira letra da sequência que seria o  Q e com isso percorro o dict e retorno CAA' e 'CAG', já que eles possuem o Q no item[1] da lista

Comment: Seria isso mesmo Kaique! Para todos os elementos da string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Motivo das suas funções não funcionarem

As suas funções construídas não retornam as chaves (`keys`) por conta que você não está pegando o valor do index [1] da lista (que seria o carácter que vai ser associado com a sua variável de strings) sendo assim, não está entrando devidamente na condição do `if`.

#### Solução

Para percorrer o dicionário e obter o index 1 da lista e fazer a comparação, utilizarei o `v[1]` que seria valor do carácter e com isso fazer a comparação com a variável de string `_seq1` e após isso exibir a `key` que corresponde.

Código

```
_seq1 = 'QVQLKESGPGLVAPSQSLSITCTVSGFPLTAYGVNWVRQPPGKGLEWLGMIWGDGNTDYNSALKSRLSISKDNSKSQVFLKMNSLQTDDTARYYCARDPYGSKPMDYWGQGTSVTVSSAKTTPPSVYPLAPGSAAQTNSMVTLGCLVKGYFPEPVTVTWNSGSLSSGVHTFPAVLQSDLYTLSSSVTVPSSTWPSETVTCNVAHPASSTKVDKKIVPRD'

CODONS = {
    "UUU": ["FENILALANINA", "F", "codify"],
    "UUC": ["FENILALANINA", "F", "codify"],
    "UUG": ["LEUCINA", "L", "codify"],
    "CUU": ["LEUCINA", "L", "codify"],
    "CUC": ["LEUCINA", "L", "codify"],
    "CUA": ["LEUCINA", "L", "codify"],
    "CUG": ["LEUCINA", "L", "codify"],
    "UUA": ["LEUCINA", "L", "codify"],
    "AUU": ["ISOLEUCINA", "I", "codify"],
    "AUC": ["ISOLEUCINA", "I", "codify"],
    "AUA": ["ISOLEUCINA", "I", "codify"],
    "AUG": ["METIONINA", "M", "start_codify"],
    "GUU": ["VALINA", "V", "codify"],
    "GUC": ["VALINA", "V", "codify"],
    "GUA": ["VALINA", "V", "codify"],
    "GUG": ["VALINA", "V", "codify"],
    "UCU": ["SERINA", "S", "codify"],
    "UCC": ["SERINA", "S", "codify"],
    "UCA": ["SERINA", "S", "codify"],
    "UCG": ["SERINA", "S", "codify"],
    "CCU": ["PROLINA", "P", "codify"],
    "CCC": ["PROLINA", "P", "codify"],
    "CCA": ["PROLINA", "P", "codify"],
    "CCG": ["PROLINA", "P", "codify"],
    "ACU": ["TREONINA", "T", "codify"],
    "ACC": ["TREONINA", "T", "codify"],
    "ACA": ["TREONINA", "T", "codify"],
    "ACG": ["TREONINA", "T", "codify"],
    "GCU": ["ALANINA", "A", "codify"],
    "GCC": ["ALANINA", "A", "codify"],
    "GCA": ["ALANINA", "A", "codify"],
    "GCG": ["ALANINA", "A", "codify"],
    "UAU": ["TIROSINA", "Y", "codify"],
    "UAC": ["TIROSINA", "Y", "codify"],
    "UAA": ["STOP-CODON", "NON-codify"],
    "UAG": ["STOP-CODON", "NON-codify"],
    "UGA": ["STOP-CODON", "NON-codify"],
    "CAU": ["HISTIDINA", "H", "codify"],
    "CAC": ["HISTIDINA", "H", "codify"],
    "CAA": ["GLUTAMINA", "Q", "codify"],
    "CAG": ["GLUTAMINA", "Q", "codify"],
    "AAU": ["ASPARAGINA", "N", "codify"],
    "AAC": ["ASPARAGINA", "N", "codify"],
    "AAA": ["LISINA", "K", "codify"],
    "AAG": ["LISINA", "K", "codify"],
    "GAU": ["ÁCIDO ASPÁRTICO", "D", "codify"],
    "GAC": ["ÁCIDO ASPÁRTICO", "D", "codify"],
    "GAA": ["ÁCIDO GLUTÂMICO", "E", "codify"],
    "GAG": ["ÁCIDO GLUTÂMICO", "E", "codify"],
    "UGU": ["CISTEÍNA", "C", "codify"],
    "UGC": ["CISTEÍNA", "C", "codify"],
    "CGU": ["ARGININA", "R", "codify"],
    "CGC": ["ARGININA", "R", "codify"],
    "CGA": ["ARGININA", "R", "codify"],
    "CGG": ["ARGININA", "R", "codify"],
    "AGU": ["SERINA", "S", "codify"],
    "AGC": ["SERINA", "S", "codify"],
    "AGA": ["ARGININA", "R", "codify"],
    "AGG": ["ARGININA", "R", "codify"],
    "GGU": ["GLICINA", "G", "codify"],
    "GGC": ["GLICINA", "G", "codify"],
    "GGA": ["GLICINA", "G", "codify"],
    "GGG": ["GLICINA", "G", "codify"],
    "UGG": ["TRIPTOFANO", "W", "codify"],
}

for i in _seq1:
    for k, v in CODONS.items():
        if v[1] == i:
            print(k)
```

Output:

```
CAA
CAG
GUU
GUC
GUA
GUG
CAA
CAG
UUG
CUU
CUC
CUA
CUG
UUA
AAA
AAG
GAA
GAG
...
```

Comment: Massa, valeu Kaique!! Eu realmente estava me enrolando pra acertar a condição!! Ajudou muito